# Is there a way to delete or change your own flag on a question?

Tags: support, flags

A few times I've hit the flag button on a post, and wanted to remove that flag.  Either I had misread the post due to poor writing (I usually go back and edit the post), or it answered a secondary question that was hidden within a long post, or the post was edited within the time it took me to flag it.

Sure, the flags are reviewed and often declined, etc.  But, I wonder if there is a way or should be a way to remove/edit your own flags?

Answer (score 3):

Without magic diamond mod powers, no, you can't clear your own flags. And honestly, it's not a big deal anyway. A couple of bad flags every now and again don't really matter much. Especially if they're Close or Very Low Quality flags, since bad flags of those will generally be disputed and go away from community action, without even needing a mod.

In short, don't sweat it; as long as you're usually flagging correctly, you're fine.

Comment: I just hate unfairly flagging something.  I feel like it reflects badly upon me.  I guess it's not a big deal.